# Parsing extremely nested geographic data

Tags: r, parsing

I have scraped a geoJSON file and managed to locate the data I need to get:

```
library(rvest)
raw_site <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fogocruz/mapafc/main/index.html"
rvest_html <- read_html(raw_site, options = "HUGE")
script <- rvest_html %>% html_element("body") %>% html_element("script") 
json <- script %>% html_text() %>% jsonlite::parse_json()

Crime2013 <- json$x$calls[[10]][["args"]]



Crime2013[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]] 
$lng
$lng[[1]]
[1] -43.26532

$lng[[2]]
[1] -43.26521

$lng[[3]]
[1] -43.26504

$lng[[4]]
[1] -43.26464

$lng[[5]]
[1] -43.26455

$lng[[6]]
[1] -43.26392

$lng[[7]]
[1] -43.26392

$lng[[8]]
[1] -43.26397

$lng[[9]]
[1] -43.26398

$lng[[10]]
[1] -43.26432

$lng[[11]]
[1] -43.26433

$lng[[12]]
[1] -43.26511

$lng[[13]]
[1] -43.26532

$lng[[14]]
[1] -43.26569

$lng[[15]]
[1] -43.26657

$lng[[16]]
[1] -43.26671

$lng[[17]]
[1] -43.26695

$lng[[18]]
[1] -43.26834

$lng[[19]]
[1] -43.26805

$lng[[20]]
[1] -43.26718

$lng[[21]]
[1] -43.26652

$lng[[22]]
[1] -43.26746

$lng[[23]]
[1] -43.26709

$lng[[24]]
[1] -43.266

$lng[[25]]
[1] -43.26566

$lng[[26]]
[1] -43.26552

$lng[[27]]
[1] -43.26532


$lat
$lat[[1]]
[1] -22.89113

$lat[[2]]
[1] -22.89114

$lat[[3]]
[1] -22.89105

$lat[[4]]
[1] -22.8908

$lat[[5]]
[1] -22.89079

$lat[[6]]
[1] -22.89117

$lat[[7]]
[1] -22.89117

$lat[[8]]
[1] -22.89124

$lat[[9]]
[1] -22.89123

$lat[[10]]
[1] -22.89185

$lat[[11]]
[1] -22.89187

$lat[[12]]
[1] -22.89143

$lat[[13]]
[1] -22.89164

$lat[[14]]
[1] -22.89202

$lat[[15]]
[1] -22.89264

$lat[[16]]
[1] -22.89266

$lat[[17]]
[1] -22.89263

$lat[[18]]
[1] -22.8917

$lat[[19]]
[1] -22.89119

$lat[[20]]
[1] -22.89175

$lat[[21]]
[1] -22.89091

$lat[[22]]
[1] -22.89043

$lat[[23]]
[1] -22.88976

$lat[[24]]
[1] -22.8903

$lat[[25]]
[1] -22.89072

$lat[[26]]
[1] -22.89098

$lat[[27]]
[1] -22.89113`
```

This is a singular polygon shape; I have 3618 of these, and then 3618 lines of information like such that I also need to parse and then match one-to-one, to then plot on an interactive map

For reference, the data that needs matching can be located with the line

```
json$x$calls[[3]][["args"]][[5]][[1]] %>% read_html() %>% html_text()
```

which returns

`[1] "id    24 Triênio 2006-2008 Grupo Milícia Território CONJUNTO DO IAPC Tipo Conjunto habitacional Bairro CACHAMBI Município Rio de Janeiro "`

here, the first argument is what class of information it is ( id ) , ( Trienio), (Grupo) and the following is the information that it needs to show up (24), (2006-2008), (Milicia)...

How can I go about parsing that and then matching it?

I tried using unnest() but I dont get how I can do the tibble() first - or if that is the correct direction.

Comment: what does the expected output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you started.

First I loop through the list `Crime2013` (I could only go up to 2022) and then pull out the lng, lat and name of the location. Then I `rbind` the list to have a data.frame of lng, lat, and location name.

```
geolist  <- lapply(1:2022 ,function(x) {bind_cols(
lng = unlist(Crime2013[[1]][[x]][[1]][[1]]$lng),

lat = unlist(Crime2013[[1]][[x]][[1]][[1]]$lat),

location = json$x$calls[[3]][["args"]][[5]][[x]] %>% read_html() %>% html_text()) })

geodf <- do.call(rbind, geolist)
```

Comment: For some god-forsaken reason, the lapply does not work at 'location', but doing

`a <- json$x$calls[[3]][["args"]][[5]]
 
geolist1  <- lapply(1:3618 ,function(x) {bind_cols(location = a[[x]] %>% read_html() %>% html_text()) }) `

works just fine

Answer (score 0):

I parsed this using the CRAN [rjsoncons](https://mtmorgan.github.io/rjsoncons) package with a [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org)
query to identify the paths to the polygons.

```
json <-
    script |>
    html_text()
polygons <- j_pivot(json, "x.calls[9].args[0][*][0][0]", as = "tibble")
polygons
## # A tibble: 3,618 × 2
##    lng        lat       
##    <list>     <list>    
##  1 <dbl [27]> <dbl [27]>
##  2 <dbl [6]>  <dbl [6]> 
##  3 <dbl [5]>  <dbl [5]> 
##  4 <dbl [42]> <dbl [42]>
##  5 <dbl [6]>  <dbl [6]> 
##  6 <dbl [8]>  <dbl [8]> 
##  7 <dbl [4]>  <dbl [4]> 
##  8 <dbl [6]>  <dbl [6]> 
##  9 <dbl [13]> <dbl [13]>
## 10 <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
## # ℹ 3,608 more rows
## # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

In more detail, the JSON is quite large

```
nchar(json)
## [1] 90459526
```

It's structure can be explored with

```
listviewer::jsonedit(json)
```

The idea is to use a [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org) expression to extract the relevant
information.  I started with the *R* code from the question

```
Crime2013 <- json$x$calls[[10]][["args"]]
```

An important point is that JSON array indexing is 0-based, versus
*R*'s 1-based, so the JMESPath to query the `json` character vector is

```
Crime2013 <- j_query(json, "x.calls[9].args")  # a JSON string
```

The first polygon is acessible using a JMESPath expression to obtain a
JSON 'object of arrays', and then to use `j_pivot()` to create a
tibble

```
j_pivot(Crime2013, "[0][0][0][0]", as = "tibble")
## # A tibble: 27 × 2
##      lng   lat
##    <dbl> <dbl>
##  1 -43.3 -22.9
##  2 -43.3 -22.9
##  3 -43.3 -22.9
##  4 -43.3 -22.9
##  5 -43.3 -22.9
##  6 -43.3 -22.9
##  7 -43.3 -22.9
##  8 -43.3 -22.9
##  9 -43.3 -22.9
## 10 -43.3 -22.9
## # ℹ 17 more rows
## # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

*All* polygons can be obtained by replacing the apporpriate '0' index
with a wildcard `*`; I developed this expression by doing several
iterations of `listviewer::jsonedit(j_query(json, "[0][*]"))`, etc.,
until I got what looked correct.

```
polygons <- j_pivot(Crime2013, "[0][*][0][0]", as = "tibble")
polygons
## # A tibble: 3,618 × 2
##    lng        lat       
##    <list>     <list>    
##  1 <dbl [27]> <dbl [27]>
##  2 <dbl [6]>  <dbl [6]> 
##  3 <dbl [5]>  <dbl [5]> 
##  4 <dbl [42]> <dbl [42]>
##  5 <dbl [6]>  <dbl [6]> 
##  6 <dbl [8]>  <dbl [8]> 
##  7 <dbl [4]>  <dbl [4]> 
##  8 <dbl [6]>  <dbl [6]> 
##  9 <dbl [13]> <dbl [13]>
## 10 <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
## # ℹ 3,608 more rows
## # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

And actually the data can be extracted from the original document with

```
j_pivot(json, "x.calls[9].args[0][*][0][0]", as = "tibble")
```

Each row represents a record; a 'long' version could be obtained with

```
polygons |>
    mutate(polygon_id = seq_len(NROW(polygons))) |>
    tidyr::unnest(lng, lat)
## # A tibble: 117,680 × 3
##      lng   lat polygon_id
##    <dbl> <dbl>      <int>
##  1 -43.3 -22.9          1
##  2 -43.3 -22.9          1
##  3 -43.3 -22.9          1
##  4 -43.3 -22.9          1
##  5 -43.3 -22.9          1
##  6 -43.3 -22.9          1
##  7 -43.3 -22.9          1
##  8 -43.3 -22.9          1
##  9 -43.3 -22.9          1
## 10 -43.3 -22.9          1
## # ℹ 117,670 more rows
## # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Maybe it is worth noting that some nested elements have more than one polygon; the query here selects just the first

```
table(j_query(Crime2013, "[0][*].length(@)", as = "R"))

   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16 
3064  271  117   45   34   33   15    6    9    4    5    1    2    3    2    1 
  17   23   24   25   28   36 
   1    1    1    1    1    1
```

I don't really understand how the second query is supposed to line up
with the polygons, but it is accessible with

```
Info2013 <- j_query(json, "x.calls[2].args")
j_query(Info2013, "[4][0]") |>
    read_html() |>
    html_text()
```

Also, the implication is that there are 3618 elements along this path, but there are only 2022

```
j_query(Info2013, "[4].length(@)", as = "R")
## [1] 2022
```